# Pass array values from EditorTemplates to Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to pass just the EditorTemplate values back to the controller via an ajax call? I have a form that shows repeatable items in a View.

In the main view there is a line:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Edits)
```

The model.Edits are IEnumerable and I have a EditorTemplate named EditViewModel.cshtml which displays an X number of EditViewModel objects.

Next, I'd like to pass all those Edits back to a controller throught a GET ajax call. Why ajax and not a post back? I would like to use the values in the model.Edits to dynamically generate data that comes back to a textbox on the same view.

In a nutshell, I just wanted those updated DOM items defined in model.Edits, and pass them through a controller method.

This is what I have in HTML source:

```
<fieldset class="the-fieldset">
    <legend class="the-legend">
        New <strong>Unit A</strong> record
    </legend>
    <input id="Edits_0__Type" name="Edits[0].Type" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="Edits_0__Days" name="Edits[0].Days" type="text" value="" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="the-fieldset">
    <legend class="the-legend">
        New <strong>Unit B</strong> record
    </legend>
    <input id="Edits_1__Type" name="Edits[1].Type" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="Edits_1__Days" name="Edits[1].Days" type="text" value="" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="the-fieldset">
    <legend class="the-legend">
        New <strong>Unit C</strong> record
    </legend>
    <input id="Edits_2__Type" name="Edits[2].Type" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="Edits_2__Days" name="Edits[2].Days" type="text" value="" />
</fieldset>
```

Of course via ajax, there is no PostBack so those values aren't populated in the parameter back at the controller method.

What would be the best way to collect all those values and pass those to the controller?

Thanks.

Comment: You just need to use `$.ajax({ data: $('form').serialize(), // other ajax options });` and then in the POST method, bind to a parameter which is the same type as the model in the view.

Comment: just use POST instead of GET then? No biggie?

Comment: It could still be a `method: 'Get',` if it was a tiny collection, but it would create an ugly query string and could easily exceed the query string limit and throw an exception, so you should be using a POST

Comment: Yeah, I had that limit when trying the form.serialize with GET before. Was just trying to figure out another way, guess its ok with POST! Go ahead and make your comment an answer and I'll mark it up.

Comment: You don't need the `form_to_json()` function. This is all handled correctly just using `data: $('form').serialize(),` and removing `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (and as a side note - that function will fail if any of your form controls are generated using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Edits[i].SomeProperty)` where as the `.serialize()` will post back correctly.

Comment: ding-ding-ding, we have a winner! Simple as it can be. Thanks @StephenMuecke